# Symfony2 + doctrine2: Switch to metadata driver "yml"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

a short question: How to switch to the another metadata driver than annotation. How to set the metadata driver "yml" in the config.yml?

I`ve searched google and the symfony2 docu, but didnt find anything :(

thanks

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to do that with the `doctrine:mapping:convert` command

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert --force yml ./src/
```

Double check all the options available before you run the command, though

```
php app/console help doctrine:mapping:convert
```

Comment: thx. now i got yml-files. but how to switch to the yml-metadatadriver, so that doctrine2 uses the yml files instead of the annotations?

Comment: Uh, I don't think you have to do anything else. So long as you no longer have the annotations on your Entity classes, clearing your cache should be all that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an older question but you can explicitly require that doctrine use the yml driver for meta data like this:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    entity_managers:
      mappings:
        MyBundleName:
          type: yml
          dir: path/to/ymlmetadata
```

Be aware that if you use this configuration style then you have to put the "defaults" config node under entity_managers instead of its usual location.